# What percent of nodes are miners?

Tags: full-node

Miners run full nodes but full nodes may not necessarily be miners. Is there a way to figure out the proportion?

Answer (score 2):

The two are entirely uncorrelated.

There's no requirement for a miner to run a fully validating node at all.